# Attach Debugger to Outlook Desktop 2016 Version

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

I have installed an add-in in my outlook 2016 using an XML file. After clicking on a plugin sidebar, its opens.

Now I want to debug the issue (by getting console logs and network logs) that why it is not proceeding to the next screen after loading. **If it was working, it will load the configuration from an external endpoint and proceed to the next screen**.
*keeping in mind that I don't have the access to source code.*

This plugin is working fine for the web and other desktop versions of outlook but not on outlook 2016.

[image]

Comment: You need to publish the manifest file and source code if you want to get any valuable feedback there. Are you able to reproduce the issue with a newly created empty add-in project?

Answer (score 0):

First step is to determine the underlying browser used to execute your add-in in Outlook 2016. Here's the documentation to help you determine that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

If it is Internet Explorer, run `C:\windows\system32\f12\IEChooser.exe`, and just click on the slab that corresponds to your add-in's HTML page. Alternatively, you can follow the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-tools-ie

If it is Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML), install [Edge DevTools Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). Afterwards, open it, and then attach it to the target that corresponds to your add-in's HTML page. Alternatively, you can follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-devtools-edge-legacy

If it is Microsoft Edge (WebView2), simply right-click in the add-in's taskpane, and select **Inspect**. Alternatively, you can follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-devtools-edge-chromium

In general, this is a good starting place for documentation on debugging your add-in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-overview